# Dynamically display data from csv file into drop down list

Tags: php

I have a csv file that contains a bunch of states in one column of its table. I need to take those states and populate a drop down list with them *with no repeats*

My code for this is

```
//make unique array
for ($i=0; $i<count($array); $i++)
 {
 $state_array[$i]=$array[$i][1];
 }

//display in drop down list
$state_array=array_unique($state_array); 
$state_array=array_values($state_array); 

for ($i=0; $i<count($state_array); $i++)
    {
    echo "<option value='".$state_array[$i]."'>".$state_array[$i]."</option>";
    }

?>
</select>
```

The csv file is outputted to a multidimensional array and the index for the states is $array[$i][1]

There's something wrong with my code as the select box remains blank. Can anyone spot what's wrong please? Any help is appreciated.

**Note:** If it counts, I'll just mention that I can't use SQL, Java, etcetc. Only php.

Comment: Did you check the [HTML] source if there isn't any malformed HTML?  In case your values themselves contain a single quote then you might have a problem.

Comment: Sorry, could you explain what you mean by 'a single quote'?

Comment: do a `var_dump($state_array)` after each manipulation you're doing there. If you end up with an empty array after array_values, you'll end up with no options.

Comment: @user1344705 assuming if one of your values is something like `O'reilly` then it would break the HTML since you are using constructing the option like `<option value='$value'>`.  So you should be converting quotes to HTML entities.

Comment: @MarcB once I do my $state_array, the var_dump gives me null. Would you happen to have any idea why it does this?

Comment: Then check $array, since that's where it all begins.

Comment: @user1344705 where are you initializing or creating `state_array` [= array()]? Is `var_dump` returning you `null` or empty array?

Comment: @g13n all my states are in their shortened version (i.e AK, AL, etc) so the quotes shouldn't be a problem. I am however getting null results when I do a var_dump(); on my $state_array. There is something wrong with how I did that part

Comment: @MarcB I have checked $array and it's giving me the right values, it's only with $state_array that it turns null

Comment: @user1344705 then you need to initialize `$state_array = array()`.

Comment: @g13n do I just add that into my code?

Comment: @user1344705 yep before the first `for` loop

Comment: @g13n ah, it gave me this error: _Fatal error: Function name must be a string_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$state_array = array();
//make unique array
for ($i=0; $i<count($array); $i++)
{
    $state_array[$i]=$array[$i][1];
}
```